# Can php skip part of my code by some (server) error?

Tags: php

**Edit:** I shall simplify my question: is it ever possible (maybe due to a server error) PHP skips a line (or part) of my code?

For example I have this code:

```
$number = 10;
$number += 6;
$number += 4;

echo $number;
```

Is it *ever* possible the number echoed is not 20, but 10, 16, or 14 because a line was skipped due to an error?

Comment: Why not just use `is_array()`?

Comment: Or rather `in_array()`, actually. But anyway, if there is an error, no more code will be executed, nowhere, so what do you fear exactly?

Comment: Is this normal your first function doesn't return anything ? you could do something bit sorther with `return count(array_filter($array, function($e) { return $e === "A"; })) === 0;` if you don't want do use native function

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber I think if there's a server error, the whole code will fail, no matters how many time you looped over your array

Answer (score 3):

To answer your worries first. No there will be no point where a server error can cause your function return the opposite of expected result, as long as "A" is inside your array.

However, you seem to have done way too much coding for something that already exists.

You should use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$array = ["A", "F", "B", "G"]
if( in_array( "A", $array ) ) { 
    // Do stuff 
} else { 
    // Do something else 
}
```

If you want it to be case insensitive:

```
$array = ["A", "F", "B", "G"]
if( in_array( strtolower("A"), array_map('strtolower', $array) ) ) { 
    // Do stuff 
} else { 
    // Do something else 
}
```

Comment: Ole, thx for your suggestions for the built-in functions, but this is insignificant (I mean, I know I could do that). My question is all about whether or my first function could ever return true even though it should be false by the test in the loop (by some sort of server error). I hope you understand, and it seems like you already answered that part, but I would want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Well, it won't. As others stated in the comment section, if the server went through some issue, your code would just stop to execute. If for example $array somehow got converted from an array to a string (won't happen by server fault), the code would just break and execution stop. Errors in output is usually from error in input, caused by dynamic input data being changed from expected format, or from bad coding :)

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that up. I was afraid that in PHP an exception could be thrown and the execution would continue.

Comment: If an exception is thrown, PHP will abort any further operation unless you implement functionality to catch it: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp